# How to make permanant changes to /sys/devices/platform/?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, trackpoint

I'm configuring my thinkpad's trckpoint using the following command:

```
sudo echo -n 120 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/speed
sudo echo -n 255 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/sensitivity
```

But I have to run it after reboot. Is there anyway to make this change permanant?

Answer (score 0):

You could add these into a startup script that gets executed at boot.  That would be easiest.

Another way would be to recompile the Linux kernel and set the defaults of these parameters to  what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

As @mdpc says, the best way to do that is in the startup script.  I've done something similar (this should work on most distros).

Add the following lines to /etc/rc.local anywhere before the last line "exit 0"  (If exit 0 does not exist, just add them to the file)

echo -n 120 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/speed
echo -n 255 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/sensitivity

Comment: Hi David, I tried to pu the 2 lines into `/etc/rc.local` but after reboot, it did not work... I'm using Linux Mint

Comment: Looks like my formatting got munged - did you put that in as 1 line or 2 ?  (There should be a line break before the second echo).

Comment: here is my file: http://pastebin.com/VHqg9eik

Comment: That looks correct to me.  Not sure what to advise from here.  The obvious thing to check is if the script is running.  You can do this by adding a line "/bin/date > /tmp/date.log" before the exit 0  and rebooting.  If it creates/adds to a file /tmp/date.log on reboot with the date inside then the script is running on startup, if not we could investigate why.   (Are the permissions set correctly on /etc/rc.local - chmod 755 /etc/rc.local  ?)  If it is running, maybe something is overriding your config ?

Comment: Eh... Seems it's running now...